# Create new columns in one pass based on values of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created a pandas dataframe that I want to apply a couple of functions, to create two new columns based on the values of a column in the dataframe. Let's say the original dataframe is like this:

```
    name    sum
0   attr_1  900
1   attr_2  20000
2   attr_3  60000
```

I want to create a function that creates two new columns based on the sum column like this:

```
    name    sum      score    rank
0   attr_1  900      0        low
1   attr_2  20000    3        med
2   attr_3  60000    7        high
```

Right now I have a simple if statement that goes row by row and assigns the `score` column, and then I would create the same logic for the `score` column to create the `rank` column:

```
def score(row):
    val = None
    if row['count_sum'] < 1000:
        val = 0
    elif 1000 < row['count_sum'] < 30000:
        val = 3
    elif 30000 < row['count_sum'] < 70000:
        val = 7
    else:
        val = 10

df['score']=df.apply(score, axis=1)
```

This is just a small snippet of the logic, but the dataframe can get big, and going through if statements twice over can be costly. I was wondering if there is a way to use indexes or lists to assign these values dynamically in one go.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: How you are labeling low, med and high?

Comment: `pd.cut(df['sum'], bins=[-float('inf'), 1000, 30000, 70000], labels=['low', 'mid', 'high'])`

Comment: Based on the 3 different scores

Comment: @Erfan I would also like to have the score column as well

Comment: The code is there, adjust it a bit and you have your answer, did you even check the duplicate link?

Comment: Yes, one thing this doesn't seem to do is assign the values for less than and higher than the last values. So anything less and `1000` should be 0 and anything greater than `70000` should be 10. I'll change my original question

Comment: Try this: `df['score'], df['rank'] = zip(*df['sum'].apply(lambda x: (0,'low') if x < 1000 else ((3,'med') if x < 30000 else (7,'high'))))` @codingenthusiast